# Extract from object only fields declareted type

Tags: typescript, zod

I'm playing with Zod and GitHub's API, I have this interface defined.

```
interface Repo {
  name: string
  stargazers_count: number
}

const RepoSchema: z.ZodType<Repo> = z.any()

const ReposSchema = z.array(RepoSchema)

async function main() {
  // make an HTTP request.
  const response = await fetch(url)

  // thanks to ts-reset, json method now returns unknown.
  const data = await response.json()

  // let's use Zod's schema to parse the data into the correct type.
  const repos = ReposSchema.parse(data)

  // prints to the console, notice the types are strongly typed.
  repos.map((repo) => console.log(repo))
}
```

However, when I run `console.log(response)` I get all fields from the API, which is **correct** obviously.

Is there a programmatic way to filter out all fields from a type and kept only the declared ones?

Comment: Do you have a `zod` schema you are using to parse the response? By default zod strips out unrecognized keys so if you're using zod it should remove the other values

Comment: Yes, I have const repos = ReposSchema.parse(data)

Comment: But it contains all keys

Comment: Could you update your question to include the declaration of `ReposSchema`?

Comment: I've updated the question with the full example

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be using `z.any()`? https://tsplay.dev/WkDeJw

Comment: @vr. I want the opposite, create a type and infer the zod schema from the type. Is it possible?

Comment: Yeah but you'll be repeating yourself: https://tsplay.dev/WyqLKW

Comment: I will accept your first answer. You can post it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `z.any()`, you should use `z.Schema` to define how the zod schema should look for a particular type:

```
const RepoSchema: z.Schema<Repo> = z.object({
    name: z.string(),
    stargazers_count: z.number(),
});
```

but do note that you'll be repeating yourself.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WyqLKW)

---

You could also do it "the other way around" and infer the TypeScript type from a schema:

```
type Repo = z.infer<typeof RepoSchema>;

const RepoSchema = z.object({
    name: z.string(),
    stargazers_count: z.number(),
});
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WkDeJw)